# Process exit code is zero when server running

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a test suite, with a Main function that returns 1. However, the exit code after the application terminates is 0.

This seems to be related to a ASP.NET server I'm running in the background. If I disable the server, the exit code is 1 as expected.

This code works as expected, and the console reports an exit code of 1 (this is F# syntax, but I'm pretty sure that's not related):

```
[<EntryPoint>
let main (arts : string array) : int =
  1
```

while this has an exit code of 0, which is not what I expect:

```
[<EntryPoint>
let main (arts : string array) : int =
  MyHttpServer.init()
  1
```

Here's the MyHttpServer.init function:

```
let init() : Task =
  Host
     .CreateDefaultBuilder()
     .Build()
     .RunAsync()
```

My question: what is it about having a server running in the background that is causing the exit code to be zero? Is there something in .NET where the exit code is affected by background tasks and threads?

Note: .NET 6 preview 5, but this has happened on all versions I've used from .NET 5 onwards.

Comment: Using exit code is generally not a good idea if you have the choice. Any part of the code in processe can call Environment.Exit, or set the code (c#) or ExitProcess (winapi), %ERRORLEVEL% env variabe, for ex: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/WebHostLifetime.cs#L52. What you can do is use a debugger and put a breakpoint on ExitProcess maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Not super familiar with F# syntax, BUT I suspect that if Init() exits b/c of an error/exception, then execution would never reach the line returning a 1, and would therefore exit with a value of 0.

**EDIT:**
If an exception is thrown when calling `Init`, or if an exception is thrown before `Init` can return, the unhandled exception would terminate the process, and the code that returns `1` would not be executed.

Comment: `Init` returns a task, and the task is never looked in though. So `main` should complete before the task does

Comment: Yes, but you're assuming that the call to init can be made successfully (MyHttpServer is not null, for instance) and that init doesn't throw an exception before it can return. If I'm not mistaken, an unhandled exception will terminate the process, and therefore prevent it from reaching the point where it can return the 1.

Comment: I know that `init` doesn't throw an exception before it successfully returns a `Task`. Are you saying that the `main` function doesn't truly "return" until it cleans up (`Dispose`s?) of the `Task`, which throws an exception later?

Comment: If you've stepped thru w/ a debugger & KNOW that `Init` doesn't throw an exception & successfully returns a `Task`, then this discussion is probably moot. What I'm saying, tho, is that If, for instance, `MyHttpServer` is null, the `Init` call will never even take place & a null-ref exception will be thrown, causing the process to terminate. Similarly, if the code inside `Init` throws an exception before returning the `Task`, the process will terminate. I cannot say definitively whether `Dispose` will be called (tho I suspect it will), regardless, the code returning 1 will never be reached.